# Finding closest values to given one in array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to write some code for finding indexes of two closest values from two given ranges. Exactly I would like to reproduce something like this:
[Plot sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gbh2A.png)

With code:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots()

for case in range(l.case_count):
    freq = l.get_frequency(case)
    V_out = l.get_data('V(wy)', case)
    Vout_amplitude = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(V_out))
    axes.semilogx(freq, Vout_amplitude)

axes.grid()
axes.set_xlabel("Frequency (Hz)")
axes.set_ylabel("Amplitude (dB)")

xmax = x[np.argmax(y)]
ymax = y.max()

text= "x={:.3f}, y={:.3f}".format(xmax, ymax)

x=freq
y=Vout_amplitud

xmax = x[np.argmax(y)]
ymax = y.max()

text= "x={:.3f}, y={:.3f}".format(xmax, ymax)

axes.annotate(text, xy=(xmax, ymax))
ypos = np.where(y == ymax) 
axes.semilogx(x[ypos],y[ypos],'mo')

idx = (np.abs(y - (ymax-3))).argmin()
print(idx)

axes.semilogx(x[idx],y[idx],'mo')

value = ymax-3
f_r = np.where(x>x[ypos])
f_l = np.where(x<x[ypos])

idx_l = (np.abs(y[f_l] - (ymax-3))).argmin()
idx_r = (np.abs(y[f_r] - (ymax-3))).argmin()

axes.semilogx(x[idx_l],y[idx_l],'mo')
axes.semilogx(x[idx_r],y[idx_r],'mo')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

But all i get with this code is:
[wrong plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv3VE.png)

As you can see, one dot should be on the left side and one on the right, but something goes wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`idx_r` is the index of the rightmost dot, but only within the `f_r` array.  `f_r[0]` is somewhere in the middle of the `x` array.  I believe you want to plot `x[idx_r] + x[idx]`.

Comment: Yes, it truly is! I've tried plotting x[idx_r+idx] and it's working now. Also i've changed value of idx - now it's pointing to the maximum value of array y. Thank you for your answear and time.